# Automorphism on a kahlerian variety which acts as -id on $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I've read this proposition:

"there is no automorphism (biholomorphic map) of a Kahlerian complex manifold $X$ which acts on $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ as $-$identity"

so I tried to prove this statement and i would like to ask you if I'm correct. Here is as I proceed:

Suppose there is such an automorphism, call it $f$. Then $f^*$ brings a Kahler class $\omega$ to $-\omega$. Writing $\omega$ as $g(I-,-)$, where $g$ is a kahlerian metric, this means that $f^*$ brings $g(I-,-)$ to $-g(I-,-)$. That means that on the second copy of $X$ there should be a riemannian metric $-g$, but it is not an inner product on the tangent bundle (for the positive condition).

Comment: How are you explicitly using the fact that $f$ is holomorphic?

Comment: i realized i didn't specify that $I$ is the complex structure.. anyway seeing $I$ as an integrable almost complex structure, the fact that $f$ is holomorphic means that $f_*I=If_*$ on the tangent spaces $T_pX$. So $f_*$ must bring a $(1,0)$ tangent vector to a $(1,0)$ tangent vector and so the minus sign must go on the riemannian metric.

Comment: OK. I prefer to think about the fact that $\omega^k/k!$ is the induced volume form on $k$-dimensional complex submanifolds.

Comment: well.. but wouldn't it work only if the complex dimension $k$ is odd? because if it's even then $f^*$ sends the volume form to itself and there is no problem in that

Comment: Yup, sure. But apply it with $k=1$ :)

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but here is an answer (probably the simplest one).

The trick is to consider the Kahler cone $K_X\subset H^2(X, {\mathbb R})$. It consists of cohomology classes of Kahler forms on $X$ and is open and convex. It is invariant under the natural action of the group of biholomorphic automorphisms of $X$ (pull-back of a Kahler metric is another Kahler metric). Since $K_X$ is convex (and does not contain $0$) it cannot be invariant under the map $-id$. Therefore, no biholomorphic automorphism of $X$ can induce $-id$ on $H^2(X, {\mathbb R})$. qed

What I do not know however is the situation with non-Kahler complex manifolds (provided that $H^2(X)\ne 0$ of course).